# Navigate (highlight) a specified row in a table

Tags: javascript, dom

How can I go about creating a specific function or building onto the existing code below that would allow me to go to (highlight) a specific row in a table. It is noted that the table headers should be always be exempt, therefore, start the row count at '0' after the table headers.

Ie. `function goToRow('3')`

and this function would highlight row 3

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#mstrTable {
     border: 1px solid black
}
#mstrTable td, th {
     border: 1px solid black
}

#mstrTable tr.normal td {
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
}
#mstrTable tr.highlighted td {
    color: white;
    background-color: gray;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <table id="mstrTable">
     <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>File Number</th>
        <th>Date1</th>
        <th>Date2</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Num.</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>KABC</td>
        <td>09/12/2002</td>
        <td>09/12/2002</td>
        <td>Submitted</td>
        <td>0</td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>KCBS</td>
        <td>09/11/2002</td>
        <td>09/11/2002</td>
        <td>Approved</td>
        <td>1&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>WFLA</td>
        <td>09/11/2002</td>
        <td>09/11/2002</td>
        <td>Submitted</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>WTSP</td>
        <td>09/15/2002</td>
        <td>09/15/2002</td>
        <td>In-Progress</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

<script type="text/javascript">

var table = document.getElementById("mstrTable");
var thead = table.getElementsByTagName("thead")[0];
var tbody = table.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];

tbody.onclick = function (e) {
   e = e || window.event;
   var td = e.target || e.srcElement; //assumes there are no other elements inside the td
   var row = td.parentNode;
    alert('Row is ' + (row.rowIndex - 1))
   if (this.lst&&this.lst!=row){
    this.lst.className='';
   }
   row.className = row.className==="highlighted" ? "" : "highlighted";
   this.lst=row;
}

thead.onclick = function (e) {
   e = e || window.event;
   var th = e.target || e.srcElement;  //assumes there are no other elements in the th
   alert(th.innerHTML);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What have you tried or researched so far? http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/default.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://goo.gl/GUsZZ) is a small example of how you can achieve it with jQuery.

Comment: Since I don't want to use jQuery, what would the manual way be to accomplish this?

Comment: There many ways. [Here is updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/RWxJX/3/). It is much more simplier with jQuery.